# Using JNIEnv from a nasm-created dll

Tags: java, assembly, java-native-interface, nasm, jnienv

I've been trying to call the JNIEnv function GetVersion (for starters),
which has the index 4 (according to [this site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html)).

I've been using [this site](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/10/19/invoking-assembly-language-from-java.html) for reference and adapting the masm-code to nasm by using [ebp + x] instead of the param name.

The following class and assembly file should create a gibberish number output, but instead an error message directs me to a logfile.
In this very big logfile I find it particularly interesting that the so-called register to memory mapping does not seem to recognize the contents of the registers as the JNIEnv function (in eax) but as unknown value.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I'll append the log on request only since it's fairly large.

Java code:

```
public class Ver {
  private static native int ver();
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary("my32");
    System.out.println(ver());
  }
}
```

ASM code:

```
;my32.asm
segment .text
;JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Ver_ver
;  (JNIEnv *, jclass);
global _Java_Ver_ver
_Java_Ver_ver:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx

    mov ebx, [ebp+8]
    mov eax, [ebx]

    mov ebx, eax
    mov eax, 4
    mov ecx, 4
    mul ecx
    add ebx, eax
    mov eax, [ebx]
    push dword [ebp+8]
    call [eax]

    pop ebx
    pop ebp
    ret 8
;assembled using nasm -fwin32 my32.asm
;linked using gcc -o my32.dll -shared my32.obj
;with mingw-gcc
```

Hoping this can be considered an interesting question with a SSCE
Yours sincerely
mmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've got one indirection too many:

```
mov ebx, [ebp+8]   ; ebx = env
mov eax, [ebx]     ; eax = *env
...
mov eax, [ebx]     ; eax = (*env)->GetVersion
...
call [eax]         ; call *((*env)->GetVersion)
```

So the `call` ought to be `call eax` (without brackets).

Also, you could remove your method of offsetting `ebx` and just do `mov eax, [ebx + 16]`. Or use `call [ebx + 16]`.

Comment: You might have intended to write "call [eax +16]" after the first two mov's and the push (instead of ebx). This works, many thanks!